# “Session state has created a session id, but cannot save it because the response was already flushed by the application.”

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, session, asp.net-session

we are getting strange error when our web layer makes a call to service layer.As per our investigation, when our Web layer calls WCF service service was able carry its operations but when it tries to send the response back to Web layer it is throwing below error and this error seems to be happen only for the first service request that our web layer makes meaning once we got this error if we do refresh the page the error goes away and everything seems fine.

In local machine sometimes i was able to reproduce this behavior if i rebuild the solution and lunches the app in debug mode but not always.

i tried adding void string sessionId = Session.SessionID; but it didn't work and we are not using any flushing statements in our code.

Please advise!!!

Comment: did you find a way to fix this? we are having the same problem. thanks.